# Align icon on the top of text HTML

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to align an icon on the top of an HTML h4. I am unable to do it, so I posted a question here.

how I want to the dev look:

```
ICON
TEXT
```

How it actually look:

```
ICON
    TEXT
```

html:

```html
  <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="about">
        <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">À Propos</h3>
        <div class="w3-row-padding w3-grayscale" id="noo">
           <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
             <i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i>
             <h4>Un service de qualité</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
             <i class="fas fa-file-code"></i>
             <h4>Nous prenons soin du développement</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
             <i class="fas fa-server"></i>
             <h4>Services d'hébergement par hostmyserver</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
             <i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
             <h4>Des items inédits</h4>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Css:

```css
#noo i {
  font-size: 48px;
}
#noo h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Output:

[image: this]

How I want it to look:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using icons from FontAwesome, try centre-aligning those as well. Then your CSS will look as follows:

```
#noo i {
  font-size: 48px;
}

#noo h4, #noo i {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```css
#noo {
display:grid;
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}

or 

#noo {
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this , it will work

```
#noo div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
 }
```